# How to stop WebForm_doPostBack() conditionally?

Tags: asp.net

I need to run some script by onclick() of some , checkbox particularly, to decide should i invoke WebForm_doPostBack() or not.

If I will submit form in myScript() myself, it will not cause validation of another asp.net validators, so I really need a native WebForm_doPostBack() call.

Should I handle a submit form event or are there any more "asp.net" ways to do it?

CustomValidators don't work with checkboxes:).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you do not want to validate the checkbox on submit with the rest of the form, but you want to validated it seperatly onclick? – PortageMonkey 0 secs ago

Answer (score 0):

Don't you try simply putting your own validation at submit button like that :

```
btnSubmit.Attributes["onclick"] += "return myValidation();";

<script>
    function myValidation()
    {
      // if you do not want to postback just return false...
      return true;
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT :** You can use [Page_ValidationActive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb52a4x0.aspx) to programmatically enable / disable the client side validation of your page.

> Page_ValidationActive   A Boolean
>   value that indicates whether
>   validation should take place. Set this
>   variable to false to turn off
>   client-side validation
>   programmatically.

Comment: if it will be no WebForm_doPostBack() at all - it will not cause validation for other validators. 
if it will be - how I will stop it?

Comment: SO if I understand you correctly, you do not want to validate the checkbox on submit with the rest of the form, but you want to validated it seperatly onclick?

Comment: i want to make my validation and then let (or not) asp.net do its own.

Comment: So to summarize:  Click CheckBox, run validation code and conditionally postback?  Or Click Checkbox, validate all controls including checkbox?

Comment: Click Checkbox, run validation code and then conditionally validate all other controls including checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Just to ensure your assumptions that custom validators do not work with checkboxes is not the ONLY reason for wanting to handle the checkbox click seperately, here is some code that will validate checkboxes using ASP.NET custom validators.

Custom Validators have a ClientValidationFunction property that is called automatically when the __doPostback is called or the form is submitted.

```
//The Script
function validateCheckBox(source, arguments)
{
    if(!source.checked) arguments.IsValid = false;//set IsValid property to false

}

//The Validator
<asp:CustomValidator ID="validateCheckbox" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CheckBox1" ErrorMessage="You REALLY need to check this!" Display="Static" ClientValidationFunction="validateCheckBox"/>
```

Comment: you cannot assign ControltoValidate property to checkbox. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28VS.71%29.aspx